# WCF Large SOAP Request Exception 400 Bad Request

Tags: wcf, soap

I am looking for solution to my WCF Error 400 Bad Request with SOAP request longer than 64K. I know there are a lot of solutions out there when I google it. However, I am still not successful in fixing my site to work. Hence, I am seeking for professional advice here.

**Client Side Code:**

```
Private Sub Calculate()
    Dim svc As New XXXService.XXXServiceClient
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim attributes As List(Of XXXService.AttributesStruct)
    Dim calculateSingleResponse As XXXService.SingleXXXResponseStruct

    Try
        attributes = New List(Of XXXService.AttributesStruct)
        attributes.Add(New XXXService.AttributesStruct With {.AttributesKey = "A_One", .AttributesValue = "1"})
        attributes.Add(New XXXService.AttributesStruct With {.AttributesKey = "A_Two", .AttributesValue = "XXX"})
        attributes.Add(New XXXService.AttributesStruct With {.AttributesKey = "A_Three", .AttributesValue = "1"})
        attributes.Add(New XXXService.AttributesStruct With {.AttributesKey = "A_Four", .AttributesValue = "0"})
        attributes.Add(New XXXService.AttributesStruct With {.AttributesKey = "A_Five", .AttributesValue = "1"})
        attributes.Add(New XXXService.AttributesStruct With {.AttributesKey = "A_Six", .AttributesValue = "70"})
        attributes.Add(New XXXService.AttributesStruct With {.AttributesKey = "A_Seven", .AttributesValue = "80"})
        attributes.Add(New XXXService.AttributesStruct With {.AttributesKey = "A_Eight", .AttributesValue = "09.12.2012"})
        attributes.Add(New XXXService.AttributesStruct With {.AttributesKey = "A_Nine", .AttributesValue = "12.12.2012"})
        attributes.Add(New XXXService.AttributesStruct With {.AttributesKey = "A_Ten", .AttributesValue = "15.11.2012"})
        i = 0
        While i < 80
            attributes.Add(New XXXService.AttributesStruct With {.AttributesKey = "A_Eleven[" & i.ToString & "]", .AttributesValue = "2"})
            attributes.Add(New XXXService.AttributesStruct With {.AttributesKey = "A_Twelve[" & i.ToString & "]", .AttributesValue = "5"})
            attributes.Add(New XXXService.AttributesStruct With {.AttributesKey = "A_Thirteen[" & i.ToString & "]", .AttributesValue = "1"})
            attributes.Add(New XXXService.AttributesStruct With {.AttributesKey = "A_Fourteen[" & i.ToString & "]", .AttributesValue = "NA"})
            attributes.Add(New XXXService.AttributesStruct With {.AttributesKey = "A_Fifteen[" & i.ToString & "]", .AttributesValue = "0"})
            attributes.Add(New XXXService.AttributesStruct With {.AttributesKey = "A_Sixteen[" & i.ToString & "]", .AttributesValue = "0"})
            i = i + 1
        End While
        attributes.Add(New XXXService.AttributesStruct With {.AttributesKey = "A_Seventeen", .AttributesValue = "0"})
        attributes.Add(New XXXService.AttributesStruct With {.AttributesKey = "A_Eighteen", .AttributesValue = "0"})
        attributes.Add(New XXXService.AttributesStruct With {.AttributesKey = "A_Nineteen", .AttributesValue = "0"})
        calculateSingleResponse = _
            svc.Calculate("Test", True, "XXX", attributes.ToArray(),{"P_XXX"})                  
        svc.Close()
        Response.Write("********************************************<br/>")
        Response.Write("[ErrorCode: " & calculateSingleResponse.ErrorCode & "]<br/>")
        Response.Write("[ErrorDescription: " & calculateSingleResponse.ErrorDescription & "]<br/>")

    Catch ex As Exception
        Response.Write("EXCEPTION:" & "<br/>" & ex.Message & "<br/>" & ex.StackTrace & "<br/>")
        If Not ex.InnerException Is Nothing Then
            Response.Write("INNER EXCEPTION:" & "<br/>" & ex.InnerException.Message & "<br/>" & ex.InnerException.StackTrace)
        End If
    End Try

End Sub
```

**Client Side Config:**

```
<system.web>
  <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2147483647" />
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
   <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
</system.webServer>
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IXXXService" closeTimeout="10:01:00"
      openTimeout="10:01:00" receiveTimeout="10:10:00" sendTimeout="10:01:00"
      allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="true" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
      maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
      messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
        maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
      <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
          realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
      <behavior name="BasicHttpBehaviour_IXXXService">
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483646" />
      </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://127.0.0.1:999/XXXService.svc"
    behaviorConfiguration="BasicHttpBehaviour_IXXXService" binding="basicHttpBinding"
    bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IXXXService" contract="XXXService.IXXXService"
    name="BasicHttpBinding_IXXXService" />
</client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

**Server Side Config:**

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
        <service name="WcfClient.XXXService">
            <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IXXXService"
                contract="WcfClient.IXXXService" />
            <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
            <host>
                <timeouts closeTimeout="00:01:10" openTimeout="00:01:00" />
            </host>
        </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
        <wsHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IXXXService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                bypassProxyOnLocal="true" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
                messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true"
                allowCookies="false">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                    maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
            </binding>
        </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior>
                <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
                <!-- For wcf caller to receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
                <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483646"/>
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found the issue myself:

1. Binding between server side and client side must be the same, hence I change both to basicHttpBinding
2. Service name is case sensitive, I changed "WcfClient.XXXService" to "wcfClient.XXXService" and it works now.

Hope this can help others with the same difficulties =)